# Using Symfony AttributeBags in a Controller

Tags: symfony, session, symfony-3.2

I've read about sessions here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

If I use the code directly, Symfony logins using `Guard` don't work on the first attempt (first time always fails, second time succeeds). So I'm guessing that I have to use the session at `$this->container->get('session')`. But adding bags to that baffles me.

I've tried this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $session=$this->container->get('session');
    $cart=new AttributeBag('ShoppingCartItems');
    $session->registerBag($cart);
    $session->start();
```

...but it tells me

> Cannot register a bag when the session is already started.

I've tried this:

...in the bundle:

```
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new \Website\DependencyInjection\Compiler\InjectShoppingCart());
    }
```

...and then this for `InjectShoppingCart`

```
namespace Website\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class InjectShoppingCart implements CompilerPassInterface {
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $bagDefinition = new Definition();
        $bagDefinition->setClass(AttributeBag::class);
        $bagDefinition->addArgument("ShoppingCartItems");
        $bagDefinition->addMethodCall("setName", ["ShoppingCartItems"]);
        $container->setDefinition("ShoppingCartItemsService",$bagDefinition);

        $container->getDefinition("session")->addMethodCall("registerBag",[new Reference("ShoppingCartItemsService")]);
    }
}
```

...which I tried to use, Cargo Cult style, from [question 44723613](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723613/how-to-add-extra-bag-to-symfony-session). Whatever it does, it does not result in the registration of an attribute bag.

No matter what I've tried so far, either `Guard` authentication breaks, or else the bag doesn't get registered. I want to do both, though, hopefully without installing Megs and Megs of external libraries.

It can't be this hard. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.

In the end, it was just one line from the example I was using that was making it fail for me:

```
$bagDefinition->addArgument("ShoppingCartItems");
```

...has to be deleted.

What this all amounts to is that in the compiler pass, instead of making it do this:

```
$bag = new AttributeBag('ShoppingCartItems');
$bag->setName('ShoppingCartItems');
$session->registerBag($bag);
```

I needed to make it do this:

```
$bag = new AttributeBag();
$bag->setName('ShoppingCartItems');
$session->registerBag($bag);
```

So `InjectShoppingCart` ends up looking like this:

```
namespace Website\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class InjectShoppingCart implements CompilerPassInterface {
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $bagDefinition = new Definition();
        $bagDefinition->setClass(AttributeBag::class);
        $bagDefinition->addMethodCall("setName", ["ShoppingCartItems"]);
        $container->setDefinition("ShoppingCartItemsService",$bagDefinition);

        $container->getDefinition("session")->addMethodCall("registerBag",[new Reference("ShoppingCartItemsService")]);
    }
}
```