# Register custom AttributeBag through CompilerPass

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to tidy up my session variables by integrating custom AttributBags into the session. In Symfony < 6.0 you were able to inject a custom AttributBag into the session service.

See related questions

- [How to add extra bag to symfony session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723613/how-to-add-extra-bag-to-symfony-session)
- [Using Symfony AttributeBags in a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727632/using-symfony-attributebags-in-a-controller)

However this approach does not work anymore in Symfony >= 6.0. This [blog article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation) explains that the session service is deprecated and must now be accessed over the request_stack service. For controllers this works fine.

My current (not working) approach looks like this: Define a custom AttributBag class.

```php
class ShoppingCartBag extends AttributeBag {
    public function __construct(string $storageKey = 'shoppingCart') {
        parent::__construct($storageKey);
    }
}
```

Add a custom CompilerPass in the Kernel class so that Symfony takes care of all changes while building the container.

```php
class Kernel extends BaseKernel {
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new AddShoppingCartBagToSessionService());
    }
}
```

The custom CompilerPass looks like this.

```php
class AddShoppingCartBagToSessionService implements CompilerPassInterface {

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->getDefinition('request_stack') //<- Works, but how to access the session?
            ->addMethodCall('getSession') // How to bridge the gap? This thought does not work. I assume it is because the session is not yet instantiated when the container is build.
            ->addMethodCall('registerBag', [new Reference('App\Session\CustomBag\ShoppingCartBag')]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly assumed, the session does not exist yet when doing this via the compiler pass.

Symfony uses a so called [SessionFactory](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4b41d178e3c073e267f12d662d7f2536f0bf895a/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionFactory.php#L36-L39) to create the session. So what you can do instead, is decorating the existing `session.factory` service with your own implementation of the `SessionFactoryInterface` and add your attribute bag there:

An implementation of this decorated session factory might look like this:

```php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SessionFactoryWithAttributeBag implements SessionFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(private SessionFactoryInterface $delegate)
    {
    }

    public function createSession(): SessionInterface
    {
        $session = $this->delegate->createSession();
        $session->registerBag(new ShoppingCartBag());

        return $session;
    }
}
```

And then you can decorate the `session.factory` via the `services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    App\SessionFactoryWithAttributeBag:
        decorates: session.factory
        arguments: ['@.inner']
```

Now, whenever a session is created, your custom bag is also registered

Comment: I will try it out later, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks again! I had to tinker some more but got it working after all. See my answer for the working code.

Answer (score 1):

That was an important clue, thank you @Spea!

I adopted his idea and created a new decorator for the session service. After some trial and error I found an answer to my problem. The solution looks like this. Notice the actual syntax is slightly different from the answer given by Spea.

Create a custom AttributBag by extending the likewise named class. Be careful to set the name of the attribut bag, not the storage key in constructor. Otherwise Symfony will throw an error when you try to access the ShoppingCartBag.

```php
namepsace App\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag;

class ShoppingCartBag extends AttributeBag {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setName('shoppingCart');
    }
}
```

Create a decorator to change the session service's behaviour to get the desired result (include the ShoppingCartBag on each session).

```php
namespace App\Decorator;

use App\Session\ShoppingCartBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SessionFactoryShoppingCartBag implements SessionFactoryInterface {
    public function __construct(private SessionFactoryInterface $delegate) {}

    public function createSession(): SessionInterface {
        $session = $this->delegate->createSession();
        $session->registerBag(new ShoppingCartBag());
        return $session;
    }
}
```

Then decorate the session service in the services.yml by adding the following piece of code.

```yaml
services:
    App\Decorator\SessionFactoryShoppingCartBag:
        decorates: session.factory
        arguments: ['@.inner']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but I just hit the exact issue with registering FlashBag. (I am upgrading my app to Symfony 5.4).

I was not too fond of decorating the session factory, given that my flash bag was registered from within the bundle.

Instead, I went for creating a listener for the `kernel.request` event and performed bag registration right there. The only trick was to pick the right listener priority:

- Give it a too-high priority (e.g. 128), the listener gets fired before the session gets created
- Given it a too-low priority and the listener gets fired after the session has been started, which is disallowed.

By using the `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel`, I was able to pinpoint the listener which gets the session created/started:

**CREATES:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()                   
Priority: 128
```

**STARTS:**

```
Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest()                      
Priority: 8
```

So basically, any priority between `128` and `8` would do just fine.

Just register your listener and you will be safe to register a flash bag.

One extra thing: I had to check if the session was already started as my app used to call listeners twice (still need to check out why?)

```
class RequestListener
{
    private $statusEngineType;

    private $flashBag;

    public function __construct($shouldRegisterBag, FlashBag $flashBag)
    {
        $this->shouldRegisterBag = $shouldRegisterBag;
        $this->flashBag = $flashBag;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();

        // We need to register the custom flash bag
        if ( $this->shouldRegisterBag && !$session->isStarted() )
        {
            $session->registerBag($this->flashBag);
        }
    }
}
```